# Getting a snapshot of incoming / outgoing bandwidth speed on an interface in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, bandwidth, usage-statistics, pooling

We were wondering how one would go about getting a quick 3 second snapshot of how fast bandwidth is being consumed on a specific interface in linux?

We have some web services we would like to delegate to various backends depending on incoming / outgoing bandwidth used at a given moment.

Our backends are writen in PHP, but ideally something that we can run via CLI (eg: linux command line app etc that we can execute within php). Once we have the info in php, we can take it from there.

Thanks.

Comment: The first four links in the "Related" section to the right of this page seem promising. What did you try? What's missing from there that you can't figure out?

Answer (score 0):

As the first, and quick comment from Mat mentioned...

I overlooked the related section to the right, and thus... The very relevant, already posted answer:

[Get the current bandwidth use in Linux with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066029/get-the-current-bandwidth-use-in-linux-with-php)